# Get Missing Marketing Icon when using Xcode to upload ionic App to iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

Since upgrading Xcode to the latest version 9.0 when submitting my ionic app to iTunes Connect I get the error:

```
Missing Marketing Icon. iOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px Marketing Icon in PNG format
```

I have added this to the `config.xml`

```
<icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
```

And added the 1024x1024 icon to both

```
resources/ios/icon/
```

and to

```
platforms/ios/myapp/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-1024.png
```

Comment: On Ionic 2, I modified `[ionic 2 project]/config.xml` in `<platform name='ios'>` section  adding a new `<icon>` tag as @BillNoble described but after rebuilding the project with `ionic build ios --prod` it does not create a new file `icon-1024.png` under `[ionic 2 project]/resources/ios/icon` neither under `[ionic 2 project]/platforms/ios/[my app name]/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/`. It looks like you need to remove the project and add it again which if I remember well will require one to go again over all the steps to renew Apple Push Notification certificates.